# Else without if error

Tags: java

so here is my code.

```
public static void play(Player player) {
    Scanner localScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(localScanner.hasNextLine()){
      String input = localScanner.nextLine();
      if(input.equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Game over, Good bye.");
        return; 
      }
      if(input.contains("north")){
        buildWorld(player, player.moveTo().connectNorth());
      } else if(input.contains("south")){
        buildWorld(player, player.moveTo().connectSouth());
      } else if(input.contains("east")){
        buildWorld(player, player.moveTo().connectEast());
      } else if(input.contains("west")){
        buildWorld(player, player.moveTo().connectWest());
      } else {
        String contents;
        if (!contents.equals(""))
          System.out.println("There is:\n" + contents);
        else{
          System.out.println("This room is empty.");
       } else if(input.startsWith("pickup")){  // <-- This is the 'orphan' else
        contents = input.substring(8);
        if(player.moveTo().moveTo(contents)){
          Object localObject = player.connectWest(contents);
          if(localObject !=null)
            System.out.println("You have picked up " +localObject);
          else
            System.out.println("You have too much damage, Game over.");}
        else {
          System.out.println("There is no " +contents);
      }} else if (input.startsWith("drop")){
        contents=input.substring(6);
        if(player.moveTo(contents))
          System.out.println("you dropped " +contents);
        else
          System.out.println("You don't have "+ contents); 
      } else if(input.contains("status")){
        System.out.println(player);}
      else{
        System.out.println("What?");}
    }
  }
  }
```

I keep getting an else without if error and I don't know how to fix it. the bolded code is where the error occurs. I have been working on this for hours and I still can;t get it to work. please, please, please help me.

Comment: Using standard code formatting would help. Your indentation and bracket placing is so random we can't be sure without reading everything...

Comment: You just **can't** do an `else`-`else if`

Comment: The standard else is basically the catch-all in an if-else chain. You can't have another else-if after it.

Comment: else is the ultimatum, no else then else if swap them.

Comment: Most IDEs won't even let you attempt to compile code with type of syntax error... I recommend using Eclipse as an IDE

Comment: One way to figure this type of problem out on your own is to remove all of the else's except for one. Start with one if-else. When that code runs, add an else if. When that runs, add another else if. Gradually build up from a simple case, adding complexity bit by bit.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that you have an `else if` following an `else`. Try moving the `else` to be the *last* of this sequence.

Also, you have two `else` statements following the same `if`:

```
else {
    String contents;
    ...
}
...
else{
    System.out.println("What?");}
```

This will cause additional problems, and it doesn't even make sense, really.

Answer (score 2):

This part is the problem:

```
    if (!contents.equals(""))
      System.out.println("There is:\n" + contents);
    else{
      System.out.println("This room is empty.");}
    else if(input.startsWith("pickup")) {
    // ...
    }
```

You can't have `else if` after `else`.